# Java | Main thread variable update | Child use updated values

Tags: java, multithreading, global-variables

```
public class App {
    initializeGlobalTable();
    for (int instanceCount = 0;instanceCount<numberOfInstances;instanceCount++)
   {
        Instance instance = new SomeInstance();
        Thread thread = new Thread(instance);
        thread.start();
   }
}
```

**initializeGlobalTable()** will initialize some object by reading data from DB. These objects are used internally by the threads.

**Challenge:** Data in DB used to update periodically. How should I update those values in my APP and pass on those updated values to the thread reading it.

Please do let me know, If I am not very clear. Any help would really be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not that difficult. You need to keep the access to the DB in one place (let's call it service layer).

Assuming your threads are only reading from the DB and not writing. All of them would have a reference to the Service. If you are using Spring, those can have an @Autowire of the Service. If you are not using Spring, use the Singleton pattern.

Depending on how often the data is changing, and how often it is read, you could consider caching the values in the Service.

It could be interesting to mark the method reading from the DB as Synchronized just for security, but as you are only reading, it should not be mandatory.